# office addin web project dropdown does not show asp.net core projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, office-addins

I was already able to successfully switch the default Web app that comes with the office addin templates with a asp.net MVC 5 solution. But after updating to Visual Studio 2015 SP2 and updating the office tools and installing asp.net core I wanted to try to switch it out with a core asp.net app.

For one thing the Manifest Designer seems to be no longer available.But in the new properties of the addin project you can now select the web app that is linked to the addin. It only shows web apps based on .net 4.5 not any of the asp.net core apps.

Do add-ins simply not work with asp.net core or is there a missing item I need to add to the core project for it to be picked up by the addin?

Comment: Hit the same issue.  Was able to manually insert the reference but the web app doesn't start when debugging the add-in```<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Web.xproj">
      <Project>{36f3f6de-f9bc-4798-9e6f-aaaaaaaaaaaa}</Project>
      <Name>Web</Name>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <RoleType>Web</RoleType>
      <OutputItemType>SharePointWebProjectOutput</OutputItemType>
      <RoleName>Web</RoleName>
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>False</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>```

Answer (score 0):

Allan's solution worked for me as well.  And by configuring the solution startup projects to multiple startup and marking both the ASP project and the addin project to Start, VS starts both.

In my case, the ASP project is actually a micro service (ASP NET CORE) of service fabric and it still works.  I have not figured out how to make ~remoteUrl work though,  so I hard coded the URL